# Rails, PHP and parameters

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I working in Rails and I need to call to an PHP-script.
I can connect to the script like this:

```
system('php public/myscript.php')
```

But I need to send some parameters with it.
How do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide command-line arguments to your PHP script:

```
system('php public/myscript.php arg1 arg2')
```

They will be available from your PHP code like this:

```
echo $argv[0]; // public/myscript.php
echo $argv[1]; // arg1
echo $argv[2]; // arg2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just specify the parameters on the command line, such as `system('php -f public/myscript.php argument1 argument2 [...]')` and they will be available in the `$argv[]` array, starting from `$argv[1]`. See the doc page [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its right way to use `system('php public/myscript.php arg1 arg2'`) as SirDarius answered .

but system command will return the true or false in that case.

system() will return TrueClass or FalseClass and display output, try it on console .

I suggest , You can use the open method on any URL to call it, so you can call your PHP script using that:

```
require 'open-uri'

open('YOUR PHP SCRIPT PATH WITH PARAMETER') do |response|
  content = response.read
end
```