# Rails, get the data returned from command line

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-line

In my previous question I had a problem with sending parameters over the command line to an PHP file. The PHP is sending an json back, but I only receive true or false.

Previous question:
[Rails, PHP and parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026109/rails-php-and-parameters/10026237#10026237)

New problem:
Ruby.rb

```
data = system('php public/jira.php param') 
puts data
```

PHP

```
$output = array(
    "total" => $total
);

echo json_encode($output);
```

**EDIT:**

Answer:

data = JSON.parse(data)

puts data['total'] #5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1563625/84631).

Basically you'll want to use:

```
data = `php public/jira.php param`
data JSON.parse(data)
puts data['total']
```

Instead of:

```
data = system('php public/jira.php param') 
puts data
```

Comment: Okay, I receive the content from my PHP, but rails doens't handle it as JSON. In Rails: jira['total'] puts out total and not a number?

Comment: Hmm... Now I receive the following error: undefined method `decode' for JSON:Module. I put require 'json' in the top, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

system() will return TrueClass or FalseClass and display output, try it on console .

I suggest , You can use the open method on any URL to call it, so you can call your PHP script using that:

```
require 'open-uri'

open('YOUR PHP SCRIPT PATH WITH PARAMETER') do |response|
  content = response.read
end
```

Or below link will help you .

[6 Ways to Run Shell Commands in Ruby](http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/ruby-shell-commands.html)